# PyQGIS: how to filter feature attributes according to symbol in the legend

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I can reach feature attributes as follows:

```
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    print(feat.attributes() )
```

This gives me whole attributes.
I want to filter attributes according to each symbol in the legend

Note that I can reach legend symbol items as follows

```
for symbolItem in layer.renderer().legendSymbolItems():
```

but I couldn't find any way to get attributes which represented by this symbolItem objects that have type of `QgsLegendSymbolItem`

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna take a look at the qgslegendsymbolitem.h file. You can access it here: https://api.qgis.org/api/qgslegendsymbolitem_8h_source.html

When you call layer.renderer().legendSymbolItems() **it will return you a list** of QgsLegendSymbolItem objects, which are described in the link i provided.

At the qgslegendsymbolitem.h you will see several attributes you can check for those objects, such as label(), symbol() and ruleKey().

Here, using QGIS 2.18, i was able to check those attributes with this code:

```
                for Index in range(len(gridLayer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2())):
                print gridLayer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2()[Index].label()
                print gridLayer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2()[Index].symbol().color().name()
                print gridLayer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2()[Index].ruleKey()
```

Alternativelly, you can access each QgsLegendSymbolItem object individually simply by using it's index in the list, like this (this will print you some attributes for the first object in that list):

```
            print gridLayer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2()[0].label()
            print gridLayer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2()[0].symbol().color().name()
            print gridLayer.rendererV2().legendSymbolItemsV2()[0].ruleKey()
```

Please note that i'm using rendererV2() and legendSymbolItemsV2() because of my QGIS version. You probably wont have to.

Best regards.